# When are multi value fields acceptable design in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, relational

If I have a table with say, a images field, I understand that it is better put images in a new table Images and link with a common ID so the number of images can expand.The rule seems to be that comma separate values are bad. 
But what if searching isn't a problem, say for internal comments or a notes field? Is it not better to have one large field in the table for clarity or should I still put the comments in a new table? What is the accepted norm?

Also, if two different tables use the same Images table, then how do I create the relation because the common ID will be different?

For example:
Product
prodID

Employee
employeeID

Images
imageID
XXXID
imgURL

what should XXXID be to be common to both tables?

should there be a table for each even if many tables use the images table eg EmployeeImages, ProductImages?

Comment: I think first question you should answer is: what makes searching so much less important for `internal comments or a notes field` than it would be for images? To your second question, if two tables reference the **same** images table, the referenced ID will be the same in both cases.

Comment: The comments field would be there to simply write notes that have no real relevance i.e."It was a nice day and the meeting went well. NB. next meeting ask if Jane passed her exams." Not say targetAreas: Liverpool, Manchester, Leeds, Birmingham.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. The question is not so much **what** you save in those comments but **where** do you need them (i.e. **how often and in what manner** will they be queried, and can you be sure that won't ever change in the future - in most cases you can't guarantee that at all and that is why you should always :-))

Comment: I really don't understand the second part. Both tables need a common ID no? In Employee employeeID and in Images employeeID. But this means Products can't use the Images table as Product doesn't have a field employeeID.

Comment: Consider that every table should have a primary key to identify rows. If you then want to use one of those rows in another table (i.e. reference it) you do that by writing the corresponding `primary key` value into the table where it is needed (referenced) as a `foreign key`, hope that clears it up a little. In your example products need images and employees do, too - so both tables (products and employees) should have a foreign key column to have a reference to the corresponding `ImageID` of the needed image's row .

Comment: I think you are saying that I have it the wrong way around. That Employee and Product contain a field imageID that references a field in Image imageID, not that Image contains a field xxxID that references Employee and Product? If so, then how does Employee reference more than one Image instance?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: If so, then how does Employee reference more than one Image instance?

Comment: You do that with a separate relationship table (so you end up having 3 for one relationship, for example: images, employees, employeesImagesRelation (One row in here could look like this: ID 1, ImageID 1,  EmployeeID 2, that way you can have the same image referenced by multiple employees and also the other way around)

Comment: I am sorry but I can't do it! I just can't see how it works. Can you amend please? I have:  [ Agent, agentID ] [ Comment, commentID, commentDate, comment ] [ Buyer, buyerID ] and you say I need [ CommentRelation, relationID ] I want Buyer and Agent both to be able to reference instances of Comment. Thanks